# How to set the design to the spinner in action bar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-spinner

[image]

My spinner is not looking good, i want to reduce gap between the text and spinner icon. also i want to provide the design..

Please help me how to provide the design

I have used below code:
main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:title=""
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

activity:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
        spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.spinner_language_array, R.layout.spinner_row);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        selectedLanguage = sharedPref.getInt(Constants.SELECTED_LANGUAGE, 0);


        spinner.setSelection(selectedLanguage);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        return true;
    }
```

spinner_row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"/>
```

Comment: You can change the design using a nine patch image, here is a tool you can use:
http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

Answer (score 0):

try changing one of these for different GUI experience

```
R.array.spinner_language_array, R.layout.spinner_row);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```